# Python CGI html form action

Tags: python, html, apache, cgi, httpd.conf

I'm trying to create a website using HTML and Python CGI running on an httpd server.
When i give the cgi file location in the html form action as

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/filename.cgi">
```

it opens up the page as 
"file:///cgi-bin/filename.cgi"

whereas it should be opening it as "127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/filename.cgi"

Can anyone tell me what I'm supposed to change to get this working??

There's no fields in the form. Just a submit button. So i dont think GET/POST is required here.

Comment: Seems like you opened your html page as a file in the first place, rather than serving it via the webserver.

Comment: ummm yes i am. I'm sorry i'm still learning. So that's not how it works?

Comment: Well not if you want to use a relative URL in the form action: if you do it's always going to submit to the same place. Either serve the page via the webserver, or use the full URL.

Comment: Could you give me any hints on how I'm supposed to do that, I've looked into it a bit but I can't figure it out. I'm guessing it's got something to do with the conf file??

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. How to do what? Which conf file?

Comment: How do i get the html file to open via the server? So far all i've been doing is clicking on it. Which opens it as a file, like you said. 
Do i have to make any changes in httpd.conf file for it to open via the httpd server?

Comment: I don't know, because you haven't posted it. Is the file in the document root? Where is it in relation to the cgi script?

Comment: yes. the html file is in /var/www/html. That is the DocumentRoot.
The cgi file is in  /var/www/cgi-bin.

Comment: Then you can just open it by going to "http://127.0.0.1/filename.html" in your browser.

Comment: oh wow. that was simple. Thanks a lot.